# vim match the outest bracket

Tags: regular-expression

How can I match the outest bracket and replace it with `$$` in vim?

For example:

```
{a+b>c} --> $a+b>c$

{a+{\int_a^bf(x)dx=\set{a+c}}} --> $a+{\int_a^bf(x)dx=\set{a+c}}$

{a+{b+c}+d} and {e+{f}+g} --> $a+{b+c}+d$ and $a+{f}+g$
```

#### UPDATE

By @Ingo Karkat's  fascinating answer, I can search and replace correctly on each file. I would like to make this more easy to operate by:

1. All my file are with filetype `tex`;
2. I would like to define a shortcut key to make the search and replace though out the file with `ft=tex`

How can I do that? (I know this is maybe off topic, and I should solve it by reading vim's doc, but it will take me a lot of time since I am just a begginer user of vim...)

Comment: Please don't drastically change the subject of your question after you've got several good answers. Mappings are straightforward in Vim; if you need any help please open a new question, and mark this question resolved by accepting the answer that helped you the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a macro approach that uses the `%` command to jump to matching curly braces. In contrast to my regular expression solution, this one handles multiple constructs in a line:

Preparation: Don't let search wrap around, the recursive macro would not end and eat into inner braces, too:

```
:set nowrapscan
```

Search for and go to the first opening brace:

```
gg/{
```

Clear register `q` and start recording:

```
qqqqq
```

Go to matching closing brace, back to front, replace, back to end, replace, go to next match:

```
%``r$``r$n
```

Recursively invoke macro, end macro recording, invoke macro:

```
@qq@q
```

Comment: Note that you can simplify your macro with: `%r$<C-O>.` to replace one, or `%%r$<C-O>.n` to replace and search next like you do.

Answer (score 2):

As long as there's only one such construct on each line, a simple greedy match (`.*`) will do. Capture the inner parts (including any `{...}` inside, up to the last available) in a *named capture*, and replace with `$`, captured text, `$`:

```
:%s/{\(.*\)}/$\1$/
```

---

Now, if there can be multiple constructs on a single line (e.g. `{a+b>c} and {a+{\int_a^bf(x)dx=\set{a+c}}}`), and you want to replace each (i.e. `$a+b>c$ and $a+{\int_a^bf(x)dx=\set{a+c}}$`, not `$a+b>c} and {a+{\int_a^bf(x)dx=\set{a+c}}$`, that's a whole different dimension. You would need to match opening and closing curly braces, something which cannot be done with Vim's regular expressions at all.

Comment: I know that php has [Recursive patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php), It seems that there is not correspondence in vim(perl)?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. A completely different approach would be a macro using the `%` command; that one can indeed jump to matching braces.

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you like plugins, you can use [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround):

```
{a+b>c}
^
cursor here, type: cs{$   (Change Surrounding { by $ )
v
{a+{\int_a^bf(x)dx=\set{a+c}}}
```

You have to move yourself to the outer *context* but once you're there, it's straightforward.

Comment: Correct, that basically simplifies the ```%``r$``r$``` part in my macro solution.